# Find duplicated users using Ruby

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

I am having trouble finding a way to find from a single query if there are users duplicated in my database.

How could I query to find dupped users in Ruby using ActiveRecord?

The database structure is here: http://www.collectivestep.com/discoursedb/

Comment: Could you add some detail ? The structure of the database table, what do you want to check ? same email (with or without spaces ) ? same login ? etc

Comment: I want to find out dupped users with the same username. This is in a discourse forum after a long import

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take an example like you want to find user that have same name and email then try this one and you will get all user that have same name and email and once you get this output delete those User,

```
User.find(:all, :group => :username, :having => "count(*) > 1" )
```

Comment: I've added the database structure which I missed.

Comment: just change `[:name, :email]` to `:username` to fit the database

Answer (score 1):

For MySql database you can try following query

```
User.find(:all, :group => [:username], :having => "count(*) > 1" )
```

For Postgres you can try following query

```
User.select(:username).group(:username).having("count(*) > 1")
```